# Simplify double for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have two matrices. Matrix A has 14 variables (but I am only interested in five variables for this exercise) and matrix B has five variables. Matrix A has 250,000 observations and matrix B has 23,000 observations. The variables are non-numeric characters (text).

My goal is to fill columns 9 and 10 of matrix A with information from columns 4 and 5 from matrix B, if columns 1, 2, and 8 from matrix A are equivalent to columns 1, 2, and 3 from matrix B.

The code I have written is a double for loop and takes about 10 days to run. I am looking for a way to simplify the code to make it more efficient and run considerably quicker (ideally in a couple of hours).

The code is as follows:

```
    for (i in 1:nrow(matrix_b)) {
      for (j in 1:nrow(matrix_a)) {
        if (matrix_a[j,1]==matrix_b[i,1]) {
          if (matrix_a[j,2]==matrix_b[i,2]) {
            if (matrix_a[j,8]==matrix_b[i,3]) {
              matrix_a[j,9]<-matrix_b[i,4]
              matrix_a[j,10]<-matrix_b[i,5]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

An example would be:

```
    # Matrix A
          [,1]   [,2]         [,8]            [,9]       [,10]
    [1,]   Z10   11 Nov 2012   Rocko Large     NA         NA


    # Matrix B
          [,1]   [,2]         [,3]            [,4]       [,5]
    [1,]   Z10   11 Nov 2012   Rocko Large     Aldi       CFO
```

In this case, the code should insert "Aldi" in cell [1,9] and "CFO" in cell [1,10] of matrix A, because cells [1,1], [1,2], and [1,8] in matrix A are identical to the cells [1,1], [1,2], and [1,3] in matrix B.

If the data looked like this (the date in column 2 is different), the code should NOT do anything; i.e., leave cells [1,9] and [1,10] in matrix A as they are.

```
    # Matrix A
          [,1]   [,2]         [,8]            [,9]       [,10]
    [1,]   Z10   15 Dec 2013   Rocko Large     NA         NA


    # Matrix B
          [,1]   [,2]         [,3]            [,4]       [,5]
    [1,]   Z10   11 Nov 2012   Rocko Large     Aldi       CFO
```

Comment: Please provice a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @docendodiscimus, many thanks for your comment. I have included an example. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that avoids the loops altogether and instead uses joins to the same effect:

```
set.seed(1)

# Create some fake data with the given dimensions
matrix_a <- matrix(sample(letters, 14 * 250000, replace = T), ncol = 14)
matrix_b <- matrix(sample(letters, 5 * 23000, replace = T), ncol = 5)

library(dplyr)

# Convert matrices to data frames
df_a <- as_tibble(matrix_a)
df_b <- as_tibble(matrix_b)

# Simplify df_b so that multiple rows from df_b don't match the same row
# in df_a: this is implied by the loop in the question, and isn't necessary
# to do for the real data, if the condition holds.
df_b <- df_b %>% 
  distinct(V1, V2, V3, .keep_all = T)

new <- df_a %>% 
  # join columns from b to a that match on the specified variables
  left_join(df_b %>% rename_all(~ paste0("b_", .)),
            by = c(V1 = "b_V1", V2 = "b_V2", V8 = "b_V3")) %>%
  # if there was a match in b, replace value in a with the value from b
  mutate(
    V9  = if_else(!is.na(b_V4), b_V4, V9),
    V10 = if_else(!is.na(b_V5), b_V5, V10)
  ) %>% 
  # drop the added columns from b
  select(-starts_with("b_"))
```

And for the time it takes: the join and mutate took 0.17 seconds on my machine.

If you want to learn more about the data wrangling tools available in `dplyr` a good place to start is the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html) and [website](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/).

---

Checking that rows that should change, did change:

```
should_change <- df_a %>% 
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% 
  semi_join(df_b, by = c("V1", "V2", V8 = "V3"))

new %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>% 
  select(row_id, V9, V10) %>% 
  inner_join(should_change %>% select(row_id, V9, V10),
             by = "row_id", suffix = c("_new", "_old"))
#> # A tibble: 181,708 x 5
#>    row_id V9_new V10_new V9_old V10_old
#>     <int>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
#>  1      1      j       k      p       m
#>  2      3      n       e      f       h
#>  3      4      s       n      v       s
#>  4      6      m       r      j       n
#>  5      7      c       v      t       k
#>  6      8      m       n      u       y
#>  7      9      m       x      l       r
#>  8     10      e       a      z       v
#>  9     11      e       q      l       k
#> 10     12      o       f      z       q
#> # ... with 181,698 more rows
```

Comment: It would be cool to have an "updating join" in `dplyr` for scenarios like this, rather than having to `left_join` and `mutate`.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, @Mikko Marttila!

I tried to run the code, but unfortunately, I get the following error message:

Warning messages:
1: Column `V1`/`b_V1` has different attributes on LHS and RHS of join 
2: Column `V2`/`b_V2` has different attributes on LHS and RHS of join


How do you think could I fix this?

Comment: Apologies for being imprecise in my first comment! If I run your code on its own, it works perfectly fine and is astonishingly fast. But if I try to run it on the real data (using the last function starting with df_a %>%), I get the stated error message. I must be doing something wrong but cannot figure out what.

Comment: That's just a warning message, you should still be getting the correct result. It's just saying that the columns 1 and 2 in your datasets have different attributes (i.e. metadata).

Comment: If you are worried about it though, go ahead and post the result of `lapply(df_a, attributes)` and `lapply(df_b, attributes)` in your question, so we can see what's different.

Comment: Mikko, thanks again for your quick reply and taking the time to help me. Unfortunately, the code seems to not work for me. To avoid any potential mistakes I could have done by applying your code to the real data, I have re-run your whole example code and compared selected rows in df_a before and after the matching. More specifically, I identified rows in df_a that should be changed because V1, V2, and V3 are equivalent to a row in df_b. However, these rows were the same after I ran the matching code; i.e., V9 and V10 of df_a did not change. Does the code work when you run it?

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. The last bit (starting with `df_a %>%`) won't modify `df_a` in place, i.e. you'll have to save the result in a new object. I'll update the answer to include how I checked the result.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! The code works amazingly fast. If I run your example code, it works perfectly. Saving the last result as a new object did the trick.

If I run the code on the real data, however, the left-join function `left_join(df_b %>% rename_all(~ paste0("b_", .)),
            by = c(V1 = "b_V1", V2 = "b_V2", V8 = "b_V3"))` seems to extend the number of rows. Would you perhaps have any idea on why this is happening?

I just would like to mention that I am relatively new to R and that I am really grateful for your help. I am learning a lot.

Comment: It's probably because there are some rows in `df_b` that have the same values of `V1`, `V2` and `V3`. You can find the data with duplicate keys with `df_b %>% group_by(V1, V2, V3) %>% filter(n() > 1)`, for example. You can then decide what to do in the case where multiple rows in `df_b` match a single row in `df_a`.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Everything works, and extremely quickly. I can't thank you enough for taking the time to help me!

Comment: No problem at all - and welcome to R and the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)!

Answer (score -1):

Using data table takes a few seconds.
I can propose you an example here :

```
rm(list = ls())

A = replicate(14, round(rnorm(250000),digits = 2))
B = replicate(5,round(rnorm(250000),digits = 2))
```

Just creating two matrix

```
library(data.table)
DTA <- setDT(as.data.frame(A))
colnames(DTA) <- paste0("A",seq(dim(DTA)[2]))
DTB <- setDT(as.data.frame(B))
colnames(DTB) <- paste0("B",seq(dim(DTB)[2]))

DT <- cbind(DTA,DTB)
```

Here I just did an unique data table DT by joining the columns together, after setting the column names to A1 to A15 for A, and B1 to B5 for B. It allows us to set conditions on the two matrix by setting condition on the column of one unique data.table.

```
DT[A1 == B1 & A2 == B2 & A3 == B8, A9 := B4]
DT[A1 == B1 & A2 == B2 & A3 == B8, A10 := B5]
```

The syntax is DT[i,j,by]. The condition on the equality of columns is in the first part of the brackets, and in the second part you set the values by :=

It will work the same way with text or factor.

Hope it helps

Comment: The matrices in the question have differing numbers of rows (250,000 and 23,000) so you can't just `cbind` them together; they'll have to be joined instead. I do like the `data.table` approach though, the syntax is nice and concise for problems like this!

Comment: Hi @denis, many thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I cannot download the "data.table" package. I get the following error message:

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
             binary   source needs_compilation
data.table 1.10.4-2 1.10.4-3              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/data.table_1.10.4-2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL

Comment: 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/data.table_1.10.4-2.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/data.table_1.10.4-2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘data.table’ failed


(the link was too long to include in a single comment)

Comment: I am using RStudio Version 1.1.383. Might that be the reason for why I cannot download the package?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I didn't understand that the matrix had different row numbers. I will try to propose an other solution.
I am using the same version of R studio as yours. I have no idea why you can't download the package.